# Exercise on the binomial options pricing model

Tags: probability-theory, finance, martingales, conditional-expectation

I tried to solve the following exercise

> Let's consider a 3 period binomial market model ($t=0,1,2,3$). We know that the current spot price is $S_0=40$ with parameters $u=1.5$ and $d=0.5$. The annual risk-free interest rate is $r=4%$. What are $$\mathbb{E}(S_3\mid S_2),\quad \mathbb{E}(S_2\mid S_1), \quad \mathbb{E}(S_1\mid S_0)$$

Now the first thing I did was to compute the value of $$S_t=S_0u^{n}d^{m}$$ in each node for $n,m\in \{1,2,3\}$ and $n+m\leq 3$. 
\begin{matrix}
 &  & & S_3=135 \\
&& S_2=60 &  \\
&S_1=60&& S_3=45\\
S_0=40 &  & S_2=30 & \\
&S_1=20&& S_3=15\\
&& S_2=10 &  \\
&&  & S_3=5
\end{matrix}

Let $\Omega_t$ be the possible values of $S_t$ at time $t$

Now we have 
$$\mathbb{E}(S_1\mid S_0)=\sum\limits_{\Omega_1} sP(S_1=s\mid S_0)=20\cdot P(S_1=20\mid S_0)+ 60 \cdot P(S_1=60\mid S_0)$$

$$\mathbb{E}(S_2\mid S_1)=\sum\limits_{\Omega_2} sP(S_2=s\mid S_1)=60\cdot P(S_2=60\mid S_1)+ 30 \cdot P(S_2=30\mid S_1)+ 10 \cdot P(S_2=10\mid S_1)$$

$$\mathbb{E}(S_3\mid S_2)=\sum\limits_{\Omega_3} sP(S_3=s\mid S_2)=135\cdot P(S_3=135\mid S_2)+ 45 \cdots$$

The unconditional probability distribution of $S_t$ should be $S_t\sim \text{Ber}(p)$ for some unkown $p$. But how can I compute the conditional probabilities? Why do I need the information of the interest rate?

I don't know if I have to use the maringale property $\mathbb{E}(S_{t+1}\mid \sigma{(S_0,\dots,S_t)})=S_t$

Comment: Dumb question but why not $S_t \sim \text{Bin}(t,p)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$E[S_{t+1} | S_t] \stackrel{(*)}{=} E[E[S_{t+1} | S_0, \cdots, S_t]|S_t] = E[S_t | S_t] = S_t$$

$(*)$ is because of [tower rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So the second equality is because of the martingale property right? So how do I know that it is a martingale?
And is there no use for the interest rate?

Comment: @Matriz Idk if $S_t$ is a martingale, but if it is then that's the answer.

Comment: @Matriz I think $S_t$ isn't a martingale but $e^{-r_ct}S_t$ is. See [Risk-neutral measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk-neutral_measure#Example_2_.E2.80.94_Brownian_motion_model_of_stock_prices)

Comment: where $r_c$ is the continuously compounded version of $r$. See p. 13,14 in [The Discrete Binomial Model for Option Pricing](http://math.arizona.edu/~flaschka/Topmatter/527files/termpapers/Stockbridge.pdf). I believe the *discounted* stock price process is a martingale with respect to $\mathscr F_t = \sigma(S_0, S_1, \cdots, S_t)$ but not under $E[\cdot|\mathscr F_t]$ but rather under $\tilde{E}[\cdot|\mathscr F_t]$ where $\tilde{E}$ denotes risk neutral measure (you use $r$, $u$ and $d$ for probabilities and not the real world probability $p$)

Comment: I notice real world probability $p$ is not given. Shall we assume those conditional expectations refer to risk-neutral measure and not real world measure?

Comment: I don't believe [stock price process is a martingale](http://quant.stackexchange.com/a/7034/7788)

Comment: I assume the risk-neutral measure. I never heard the term real world measure. So am I right, that I can apply your answer only on $e^{-r_ct}S_t$ and not $S_t$ since it is not a martingale?

Comment: $E[E[S_{t+1} | S_0, \cdots, S_t]|S_t] = E[S_t | S_t]$ does not hold?

Comment: Yes to both I guess. Try asking on Quant SE

Comment: ok, still thanks for your time and help!